# exec_run in docker-py returning Killed

Tags: docker, dockerpy

I am trying to use docker-py to run docker exec. But, it's returning Killed(after about an hour).

```
>>> import docker
>>> client = docker.DockerClient(version = "auto", base_url = "")
>>> client.containers.get("container_name").exec_run("start")
    Killed
```

Can't understand why this is happening? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: which version of docker are you using? Add the output of `docker version` to your question

Comment: Version:      17.05.0-ce

Comment: What does the start process do? May be it is actually getting killed? I am on 17.06 and a normal sleep process works for me fine

Comment: The start is suppose to start the services for a running container. So, if I have a ubuntu container up and running start is suppose to start a session inside the container

Comment: does the command work normally when you attach using `docker exec -it <containerid> bash` and execute `start`?

Comment: Yes that works completely fine, but its the docker-py that's causing the problem.

Comment: Seem like you are also using the old client. `pip uninstall docker-py` and `pip install docker`. Do this. Some code changes also needed for you

Comment: O/P of pip list -
docker (2.4.2)
docker-pycreds (0.2.1)
I think that's the latest. I can't understand the reason why it's returning Killed. If I know that, I can start from there.

Comment: No obvious reasons that come to my mind right now